# Sockets: connection refused

Tags: c, sockets

I made a TCP Client/Server and I can run it one time. But when I try to run it more than one time, it gives me the following error: "Connection refused". Here's my code.

*Client*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    int net_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in net_addr;

    net_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    net_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    net_addr.sin_port = htons(3250);

    int connection_state = connect(net_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&net_addr, sizeof(net_addr));

    if (connection_state == 0) {
        printf("Connected with the server.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Connection with the server failed. [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    char net_message[256];

    recv(net_socket, net_message, sizeof(net_message), 0);

    close(net_socket);
    shutdown(net_socket, SHUT_RDWR);

    return 0;
}
```

*Server*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    int net_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in net_addr;

    net_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    net_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    net_addr.sin_port = htons(3250);

    bind(net_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&net_addr, sizeof(net_addr));

    listen(net_socket, 1);

    struct sockaddr_in cl_addr;

    int cl_size = sizeof(cl_addr);

    int cl_socket = accept(net_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&cl_addr, (socklen_t*)&cl_size);

    int loop = 1;
    char net_message[256];

    send(cl_socket, net_message, sizeof(net_message), 0);

    close(net_socket);
    close(cl_socket);
    shutdown(net_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    shutdown(cl_socket, SHUT_RDWR);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been trying to solve the problem by many ways but I'm a newbie. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If fixing a bind error cured this problem you should have mentioned the bind error in your question. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: @user207421 He can't know that there is a bind error, since he doesn't check the return value of the `bind()` syscall.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Connection with the server failed. [%s]\n", strerror(errno));`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error indication comes from a C library function, use `perror( "my error message" );, followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Because `perror()` outputs both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.    Unfortunately, the posted code continues to execute as if everything is ok, after the error occurred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your server lacking the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option which leads to the `bind()` syscall failing. The reason is, that after a client disconnects from the server, the connection is still known by the system in `TIME_WAIT` state, to wait for late packets. These lead to the `bind()` to fail with `EADDRINUSE` if the above mentioned socket option is not set.

Use the following:

```
...
int one = 1;
setsockopt(net_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));

bind(net_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&net_addr, sizeof(net_addr));
...
```

and *do* error checks for all syscalls! That would have shown you the problem much earlier and had saved you much time.

Some more issues:

- You are sending an uninitialized buffer `net_message`
- A shutdown on a listen socket isn't sensible at all, since no connection is established on it (this here: `shutdown(net_socket, SHUT_RDWR);`)
- The shutdown on the client socket has - if at all - to be performed *before* the `close(cl_socket);`. But it is not necessary at all in that case.

Comment: The problem is 'connection refused' at the client, not a bind error at the server, and it is caused by he server only accepting one connection and then she thing down,. There may *also* have been a bind error at he server, but the OP hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: @user207421 No, the problem is, that the connection refused error comes despite the server was started. And the fact, that this answer was accepted shows, that the assumptions I made were correct. I don't mind your downvote, it just documents your lack of understanding ;)

Comment: It documents that I understand the difference between 'connection refused' at the client, which is the topic of the question, and a bind error at the server, which is the topic of your answer. If the OP got a bind error he should have said so. You don't have any evidence about who downvoted your answer. It's a secret ballot, by design, and you have no business speculating about it.

Comment: @user207421 As it is quite easy to see, the OP can't even know, that he has a `bind()` error, since he doesn't check the _return_ value (as I mentioned in the answer, didn't you read that). It is quite obvious, that you downvoted, and I am free to comment that ;))